# how to improve performance by using or not using table variables

Tags: sql-server-2008, performance, execution-plan

I have a table variable:

```
DECLARE @to_process TABLE 
(
    [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [SequenceId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
...
)


INSERT INTO @to_process
   (  Id
    , SequenceId
...
   )
  SELECT
    TOP (@recordsToProcess) 
      Id
    , SequenceId
...
```

in my stored procedure. I have investigated that insert into it spends about 66% of total execution time. 
[image]

How can I improve or optimize my code to speed up my sp execution?

ADDED:

[image]

Comment: From what I see this operation takes 66% or the current statement, not from the all batch. And this also doesn't mean it's 66% of time, but it's estimated as 66% of cost of the statement. The time could be spend elsewhere (IO, compilation..etc), it's not necessarily that biggest cost is also biggest duration. Can you show us the complete plan?

Comment: @Marian i have added plan

Comment: @garik: I personally see nothing wrong in this statement plan. Are you sure this one is taking most of the time in your procedure? Try using [set statistics IO on] and [set statistics TIME on] when executing the procedure and see if this insert is actually the statement that takes most time.

Comment: I see that you're using TOP but I don't see a sort operator. Does your TOP have an ORDER BY? If Id from the source is a primary key, have you considered declaring a primary key on the @table?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First thought...

If you have sufficient data to take this much % of the batch, use a #temptable.

When the table variable is used later, it is always assumed to have one row: there are no statistics on this table variable. So if you have several 1000, subsequent plans won't be optimal.

Temporary tables have statistics (and indexes if required etc) and can perform better for larger datasets