# @table_variable or #temp_table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, performance

I have a big user defined table type variable that has 129 columns. I will store around 2000-3000 records in this table variable at a time and pass it to various stored procedures and functions to get additional data and make modifications.  These additional data and new modifications will then be stored in a new table variable of the same type and returned to the source stored procedure via an `OUTPUT` parameter. (This is because a table type parameter can only be passed as `READONLY`.)

This is my pseudo-code:

```
  SP1
  @tmp tableType
  {
        INSERT @tmp EXEC
        SP2 (@tmp)

        INSERT @tmp EXEC
        SP3 (@tmp)
  }
```

Should I use a `@table_variable` or `#temp_table`?

Comment: Related: [What's the difference between a temp table and table variable in SQL Server?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/16385/2660)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two blogs you should look at.  The first ([here](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2007/12/19/temp-tables-and-table-variables/)) is a comparison of Table Variables and Temp Tables.  It is from 2008 and remains relevant for SQL Server 2008 R2.

The second blog entry ([here](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2010/10/12/a-trio-of-table-variables/)) deals with some of the misconceptions (missed-conceptions) regarding Table Variables; including indexing a Table Variable.

Both of these blog entries, articles, are written by Gail Shaw.

I believe the one telling item you are looking for is a Table Variable may not be passed between stored procedures while a Temp Table is able to be passed between stored procedures.  The closest a Table Variable comes to passing between stored procedures is as a User-Defined Table Type.

Passing a Table Variable as a TVP to a stored procedure has the requirement it must be defined as a READ-ONLY parameter.  This implies there will be multiple copies of the Table Variable if you want to return a modified copy of it.

All told, passing between stored procedure may be better served by a Temp Table when you want to return the passed-in structure with updated values.

Answer (score 5):

Nothing better than trying both, but I find #tempTables perform better once you get into the hundreds of records.

Comment: Add to that the fact that temp tables can have indexes, have statistics, while table variables can only have a PK. You have some details [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3968/how-to-improve-performance-by-using-or-not-using-table-variables/3969#3969).